# Use progress bar in c#

Tags: c#

I want to display a progress bar in my c# application. There is a function which I am calling on button click in my app which is time consuming and it's not possible to determine how much time it will take to complete the whole process because I am working with reading the data from Excel sheet and storing to database and all that stuff.

When I click the button the progress bar should display the proper status and when the whole process completes I want to display a message of "Completed successfully".

```
 AlertForm alert;
 private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
                    {
                        // create a new instance of the alert form
                        alert = new AlertForm();
                        // event handler for the Cancel button in AlertForm
                        alert.Canceled += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(buttonCancel_Click);
                        alert.Show();



                        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

                                                   StartConversion(txtPath.Text.Trim(), Path.GetFileName(txtPath.Text.Trim()));

                    }
}

 #region Progress bar EVENTS

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // create a new instance of the alert form
            alert = new AlertForm();
            // event handler for the Cancel button in AlertForm
            alert.Canceled += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(buttonCancel_Click);
            alert.Show();
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    // This event handler cancels the backgroundworker, fired from Cancel button in AlertForm.
    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            // Close the AlertForm
            alert.Close();
        }
    }

    // This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done.
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress.
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Show the progress in main form (GUI)
        labelResult.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        // Pass the progress to AlertForm label and progressbar
        alert.Message = "In progress, please wait... " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
        alert.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage;


    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            labelResult.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            labelResult.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            labelResult.Text = "Done!";
        }
        // Close the AlertForm
        alert.Close();
    }

    #endregion
```

`AlertForm` is an another form in my app which is used to display progress bar
`StartConversion()` method is a method which calls another method which is present inside a class which actually performs the time consuming task.

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: You pretty much said step by step what you need to do. So... just do it?

Comment: Are you working in `win-form`?

Comment: You'll find that this site is not a code writing service. You need to come here with code-in-hand to show us what you're doing and we can then help point you the right way forward.

Comment: yes i am working on winform..my code is working but when it displays the progress bar dialog i.e..alertform it doesnt display the actual progress.

Comment: what progress is it displaying then? Nothing at all or a wrong value

Comment: nothing at all.When the process is almost completed.it displays progress for  a sec or two and then displays "completed successfully".Sometimes it hides without showing progress.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using a `BackgroundWorker`

It runs in a separate thread and provides the tools to achieve both of your requirements (updating progress-information and do sth. when the operation is completed). You just need to create an instance of `BackgroundWorker` and set its `WorkerReportsProgress`-Property to `true`.

Then simply subscribe the `event`s corresponding your needs:

1. `DoWork` - performs the actual long running task
2. `ProgressChanged` - update Progressinformation (e.G. ProgressBar-value)
3. `RunWorkerCompleted` - display your success-message

Finally invoke the `RunWorkerAsync`-Method and you're done.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
var demoWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
demoWorker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                if (sender == null) throw new Exception("Not a BackgroundWorker!");

                foreach (var VARIABLE in COLLECTION)
                {
                    // do your work

                    worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage); // invokes the workers ProgressChanged-event
                }
            }

demoWorker.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.progressBar.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
            };    

demoWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                // invoked when DoWork's eventhandler terminates
                // show message
            };

demoWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); // Invokes the workers DoWork-event
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Image the following scenario:

You have an excel file with roughly 1000 rows to process. For the progress bar you can assume 10 rows is a percent.

every now and then in the backgroundworker you let it communicate with the Main thread stating how many percentages have been processed.

The backgroundworker has an event that can be used to populate your progressbar every now and then:

for example:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        var base = 100;
        var counter = ExcelRows.Count;
        var progressCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= ExcelRows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                //perform you action
                MyRow.Save();

                //report to the Progressbar
                if(i % counter == 0)
                     worker.ReportProgress(progressCounter++);
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,           ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProgress.Value = string.Format("{0}/100 %",e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some approach like this is working using backgroundworker using a different thread.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
    }

    private bool done = true;
    int percentComplete = 1;

    internal bool ImportData(IList<string> filenames)
    {
        try
        {
            // Long running task around 5 to 10 minutes

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // returning true to break from th display progress loop
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
    }

    private void button1_Click(System.Object sender,System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //fd is Browse dialog to select files in my case

        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var flist = fd.FileNames.ToList();                

            // Disable the Start button until the asynchronous operation is done.
            this.startButton.Enabled = false;

            if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(flist);
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private void DisplayProgress(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        try
        {
            percentComplete = 1;

            while (done)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                // Report progress
                if (percentComplete == 100)
                    percentComplete = 1;
                worker.ReportProgress(++percentComplete);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    // This event handler is where the actual,
    // potentially time-consuming work is done.
    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                DisplayProgress(worker);

            }).Start();

            done = ImportData((List<string>) e.Argument);

            worker.ReportProgress(100);

            e.Result = "Converted " + Path.GetFileName(((List<string>) e.Argument)[0]) + " successfully.";
        }
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            // Next, handle the case where the user canceled
            // the operation.
            // Note that due to a race condition in
            // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled
            // flag may not have been set, even though
            // CancelAsync was called.               
        }
        else
        {
            // Finally, handle the case where the operation succeeded.
            listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(Text = e.Result.ToString()));
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }

        startButton.Text = "Start";
        startButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress bar.
    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give some description also.